# pgadmin4 service won't start

Tags: linux, debian, proxmox, start-stop-daemon

I am not a sysadmin but since I can't afford paying one, I need to do the job myself ;-)

I have a lxc container running on a proxmox4 box.

```
proxmox4$ uname -a
Linux dbd 4.4.98-2-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.4.98-101 (Mon, 18 Dec 2017 13:36:02 +0100) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In the container, I installed PGAdmin4 as a service. Installation is in my home directory. I also installed systemd as it wasn't there by default. I created a `/lib/systemd/system/pgadmin4.service`. PGAdmin won't start and here is the output of :

```
$ sudo systemctl -l status pgadmin4
  pgadmin4.service - Pgadmin4 Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pgadmin4.service; enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-01-30 13:35:49 UTC; 9s ago
Process: 673 ExecStart=/home/ballama/pgadmin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)

Main PID: 673 (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)

Jan 30 13:35:49 dbd systemd[1]: Started Pgadmin4 Service.
Jan 30 13:35:49 dbd systemd[1]: pgadmin4.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Jan 30 13:35:49 dbd systemd[1]: Unit pgadmin4.service entered failed state.
```

I am stuck and do not know how to solve this. Any help appreciated of course.

Marc

Comment: Unless you know what you're doing, use the package manager (apt-get) to install software.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with the following workaround :
- install Apache and configure a virtual host that invokes pgAdmin 4 as a WSGI application

This has the advantage that :
- there is no need to start pgAdmin 4 after a reboot
- Apache can be configured to use HTTPS between the client and itself, thus making sure usernames and passowrds are encrypted